# add relative camera position to a existing camera position

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, transform, matrix-multiplication

I am calculating with ICP the transformation between two point clouds. For a sequence of images I need will have matrix Mi for the newest transformation matrix so for the point clouds Pi and Pi-1.

Not to get them all aligned I have to die matrix Mi-1 to Mi, so that I have a transformation from the position Mi back to M0 where I started.

I tested so far only with a translation so I could simply just add them together: Mi-1 * Mi

I just wanted to see, if the ICP algorithm actually works. Now I want to add rotation and scaling to it. 
Now my question is, how do I correctly do that?

I thought of maybe split the matrices in rotation and translation [R|t], and than do something like Ti-1*Ti * Ri-1* Ri, where T is [identity|t], but I don't think that that is the write way

Comment: Is your point cloud in 2 or 3 dimensions? When you say "rotation and scaling" do you mean rotation and translation? Scaling adds a whole new level of complexity to the problem.

Comment: it is 3D. The images are gathered by a Kinect camera and out of these images I create point clouds. Normal I would say without scaling, but i think there is still some involved

Answer (score 1):

Make a 4x4 matrix out of R and T such as

```
|  R   t| 
|0 0 0 1|
```

where R is 3x3 rotation matrix and t is 3x1 translation.
Then the combination of the two transformations is just a matter of matrix multiplication.